# How to get coordinates out of the business name of a company?

Tags: ios, geocoding

I am working on a Mapkit App and I want to show annotations according to the business name of a company, e.g., "Apple Inc.".

Do you know, how the coordinates can be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding -- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder

Comment: Hi Jake(or not?:)), I read the link but there at least you need an address to get the coordinates? I want to get the coordinates out of a company name. Is this also mentioned in the link, I think not? Or I am missing anything?

Comment: Geocoding is getting coordinates by use of an address/name, Reverse geocoding is getting the address by coordinates. So it is both possible and I believe both described in that document (because CLGeocoder can do both). It should be possible to do it just by name, Google does this as well and Maps uses the same methods.